# Pandas merge by mapping

Tags: python, pandas, merge, reference, mapping

I have 3 dfs:

df1:

```
Zip County Zipcount Date

111 A 3 1/1/17

111 A 4 1/2/17

112 B 5 1/1/17

113 B 3 1/2/17
```

df2:

```
County Countycount Date

A 5 1/1/17

A 6 1/2/17

B 1 1/1/17

C 4 1/1/17
```

df3(reference table):

```
Zip County

111 A

112 B

113 B

115 C
```

**Goal:**

```
Zip County Zipcount Countycount Date

111 A 3 5 1/1/17

111 A 4 6 1/2/17

112 B 5 1 1/1/17

113 B 3 NA 1/2/17

115 C NA 4 1/1/17
```

I tried to merge df1 and df2 by Date and County but I can't make the reference to fill in the missing date.
Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`merge`+`fillna`

```
g=df1.merge(df2,how='outer')
g['Zip']=g.set_index('County').Zip.fillna(df3.set_index('County').Zip.to_dict()).values
g
Out[1014]: 
     Zip County  Zipcount    Date  Countycount
0  111.0      A       3.0  1/1/17          5.0
1  111.0      A       4.0  1/2/17          6.0
2  112.0      B       5.0  1/1/17          1.0
3  113.0      B       3.0  1/2/17          NaN
4  115.0      C       NaN  1/1/17          4.0
```